# Iguanatex and tikz in powerpoint, problem computing bounding box

Tags: tikz-pgf, powerpoint, iguanatex

I am trying to use iguanatex in powerpoint to draw a tikz picture with the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{MOOCblue}{RGB}{8,138,224}
\definecolor{MOOCgreen}{RGB}{40,159,56}
\definecolor{MOOCdarkblue}{RGB}{32,39,79}
\definecolor{MOOCorange}{RGB}{240,98,23}

\newcommand{\prob}[1]{\ensuremath{{\rm P}\left( #1 \right)}}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.65]
\draw (-2,0) -- (2,0) ;
\draw (0,-2) -- (0,2) ;

\draw[MOOCblue, thick] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,2) -- (2,1) -- (2,0) -- cycle ;
\draw[MOOCblue, thick] (1,0) -- (1,1) -- (1.5,1) -- (1.5,0) ;



\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

In fact I am trying to edit this code and I have got a powerpoint slide with the executed code on it already. However even when I change nothing and try to regenerate the code I get the error:

Error while using Ghostscript to compute the bounding box. Is your path correct?

Does anyone have an idea what is going wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Since iguanatex is based on Latex DVIpng GhostScript chain then all parts neet to be working. Which version Tex (Live or MiKTeX) will; determine how much they have installed for the DVI and GS support. so it helps if you don't know what you installed to give us version feedback from the command line when you type `pdfLaTeX  -v` also  `dvipng -version` and `where $path:gs*`

Comment: What a pity that this is not solved! I have the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the problem is already solved? The following picture is
generated from PowerPoint for Mac (version 16.51) with IguanaTex (version 1.59)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. Solved using pdflatex compiler and IguanaTex v1.60_2.

To use the pdflatex you have to download gs and imagemagick. See the [readme](https://github.com/Jonathan-LeRoux/IguanaTex/blob/v1.60.2/README.md) for more information.