# IguanaTeX in Powerpoint: problem computing bounding box

Tags: luatex, ghostscript, iguanatex

This question is essentially an exact duplicate of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487721/iguanatex-and-tikz-in-powerpoint-problem-computing-bounding-box), which alas went unanswered. I am using IguanaTeX to format LaTeX in PowerPoint (not something I’ve ever done before), and obtain the following error:

```
Error while using GhostScript to compute the bounding box. Is your path correct?
```

After a bit of Googling, I find that this error appears in the [source code](https://github.com/Jonathan-LeRoux/IguanaTex/blob/master/LatexForm.frm#L337) on line 337. There, the error comes up if GhostScript couldn’t execute or if a `.bbx` file doesn’t exist in the temporary path.  My temporary path is `C:\Temp\`, so I went to have a look and I found a `.bbx` file with contents

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

P.S. — The information asked for in the comments of [the aforementioned post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/487721/iguanatex-and-tikz-in-powerpoint-problem-computing-bounding-box) is, in my case:

- LuaTeX: `This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (MiKTeX 2.9.7140 64-bit)`,
- DVIpng: `This is dvipng 1.16 [MiKTeX 2.9.7140 64-bit]`,
- GhostScript path: `D:\MyName\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\`, which includes the `.exe` files `gsbj`, `gsdj`, `gsdj500`, `gsf2pk`, `gslj`, `gslp`.

**Edit:** The command in the source code that is to be executed is

```
cmd /C "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.15\bin\gswin32c.exe" -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=bbox IguanaTex_tmp.pdf 2 > IguanaTex_tmp.bbx
```

However, `"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.15\bin\gswin32c.exe"` is not a valid path — the closest equivalent I can find is `"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.20\bin\gswin32c.exe"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out IguanaTeX has a tab called “Main settings” in its PowerPoint interface, and it sufficed to specify the correct path there.